# Queryset Many to many 'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, django-queryset

I'm using Forms to filter the choices of a many to many relationship to only show the ones following a queryset. This is how my Form looks like

```
class ContractAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
      model = Contract
      fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ContractAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['client_year_periods'].queryset =ClientYearPeriod.objects.filter(
              Q(contract_id__isnull=True) | Q(contract_id=self.instance.id) &
              Q(client__in=self.instance.client_entity.all()))
```

**Error: 'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable**
The issue is being caused by
`Q(client__in=self.instance.client_entity))`

I need to filter the model years using the client legal model that is connected to Client Ops.

See here how is it built

[image]

Models

```
class ClientEntity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=350, verbose_name='Client Name')
    countries = models.ManyToManyField(Country, blank=True)
    operations_code = models.ManyToManyField(Client)

class ClientYearPeriod(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    [...]

class Contract (models.Model):
   client_entity= models.ManyToManyField(ClientLegal)
   client_year_periods = models.ManyToManyField(ClientYearPeriod, blank=True)
   [...]


class Client(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=3, verbose_name='Client Code')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
```

**Expected Result**

This contract has selected the client Someone

[image]

In the client Entity model it is related to Client = BEM

[image]

Here it should only show the ones Client: BEM Once it is saved (not when creating the contract as the client selected above it's not saved yet)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `client__in=…` expects a `QuerySet`, `self.instance.client_entity` is a manager, not a `QuerySet`.

But you need to make a `QuerySet` of `Client`s, so:

```
class ContractAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['client_year_periods'].queryset = ClientYearPeriod.objects.filter(
            Q(contract_id__isnull=True) |
            Q(contract_id=self.instance.id) &
            Q(client__in=Client.objects.filter(cliententity__contract=self.instance).distinct())
        )
    
    class Meta:
        model = Contract
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: I've tried that and the result is this one: Cannot use QuerySet for "ClientEntity": Use a QuerySet for "Client".

Comment: @AlexAnadon: in that case your `client__in` expects clients, but the `self.instance.client_entity.all()` is apparently a collection of `ClientEntity`s, hence the error.

Comment: Yes, That's why I need somehow to go thorugh Client_entity --> Client using the FK that links (client Legal (entity) --> Client)

Comment: @AlexAnadon: can you share the `ClientEntity` model: edit the question.

Comment: Sorry about that... Naming... ClientEntity is the same above (edited now with same name). `class ClientEntity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=350, verbose_name='Client Name')
    countries = models.ManyToManyField(Country, blank=True)
    operations_code = models.ManyToManyField(Client)`

Comment: @AlexAnadon: and how is `instance.client_entity` accessing the the `ClientEntity`s... It is unclear how you defined your relations...

Comment: It is being used in the Contract Admin. So Model Contract  `class Contract(models.Model):
   client_entity= models.ManyToManyField(ClientEntity)`

Comment: @AlexAnadon: but then you accessed the items with `self.legal_client`...

Comment: @AlexAnadon: based on the information you shared, it is `Client.objects.filter(cliententity__contract=self.instance)`... but with all the obfuscation, it is of course unclear if that is the real queryset...

Comment: Yup. i messed up with names. I've edited the question and the picture  to show you how is related.